# Reading crash log for OSX

Tags: macos, mac, crash

My 2012 Macbook Pro keeps freezing after I wake it up from sleep. Below is a typical error log I receive, but I can't decipher what it means.

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  296061 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          2
Anonymous UUID:                    E4F01ECD-FD5D-49B9-A599-A975AEEBE870

Tue Jan 29 11:22:57 2013
panic(cpu 5 caller 0xffffff8000290c4d): "VM_PAGE_QUEUES_REMOVE: unmarked page on Q"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1699.32.7/osfmk/vm/vm_resident.c:2809
Backtrace (CPU 5), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80efe93ae0 : 0xffffff8000220792 
0xffffff80efe93b60 : 0xffffff8000290c4d 
0xffffff80efe93bb0 : 0xffffff800026db74 
0xffffff80efe93ca0 : 0xffffff8000273aa3 
0xffffff80efe93d90 : 0xffffff8000274a3a 
0xffffff80efe93dc0 : 0xffffff800026e812 
0xffffff80efe93df0 : 0xffffff80005f79b0 
0xffffff80efe93e10 : 0xffffff8000654ee4 
0xffffff80efe93e50 : 0xffffff800029cf3b 
0xffffff80efe93e80 : 0xffffff8000223096 
0xffffff80efe93eb0 : 0xffffff80002148a9 
0xffffff80efe93f10 : 0xffffff800021bbd8 
0xffffff80efe93f70 : 0xffffff80002aef10 
0xffffff80efe93fb0 : 0xffffff80002daec3 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: loginwindow

Mac OS version:
11G63

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FF3BB088-60A4-349C-92EA-CA649C698CE5
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 61643538112324
last loaded kext at 981022053629: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs   1.7.2 (addr 0xffffff7f80795000, size 241664)
last unloaded kext at 263880408340: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   5.1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f80af7000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
org.pqrs.driver.KeyRemap4MacBook    7.8.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.2.6
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.2.6
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.2.6
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.2.6
com.logmein.driver.LogMeInSoundDriver   1.0.0
com.globaldelight.driver.BoomDevice 1.1
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.75
com.apple.kext.ATIFramebuffer   7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.1d2
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.2d6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   5.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.8f17
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.2.3
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.1.33
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.1.33
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.ATIRadeonX3000    7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  227.6
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController  4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 227.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  312
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 33
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.2.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   561.7.22
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.2.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.2.4b8
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 195.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   3.2.30
com.apple.security.quarantine   1.4
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   195.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   80.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.6fc18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.3d10
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.1.33
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.1.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.kext.ATI6000Controller    7.3.2
com.apple.kext.ATISupport   7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    7.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 4.0.8f17
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 230.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.4.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   420.3
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.1b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  177.8
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 331.7
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.18
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.5
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f3
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6750M, AMD Radeon HD 6750M, PCIe, 512 MB
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0000, 0x563031443353463447423236383236383133
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0000, 0x563031443353463447423236383236383133
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.198.19.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.8f17, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: ST9500325ASG, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0252, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 8
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a fairly common issue on devices that have been upgraded.

The only information I can find about a solution appear to revolve around a clean install. Some people have also had success with logging out before putting the machine to sleep